# Not able to download Android TV App from PlayStore

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

I created Application for Android TV and i uploaded application on playstore and the application is live before two days. when i open the application from link on Android TV then i am not able to download the application.

> Your Device isn't compatible with this version

here is the image of application on playstore.
[image]

I upload application many time but same issue. here is AndroidManifest file

```
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/appbanner"
        android:icon="@drawable/appbanner"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/appbanner"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```